# Code to auto dial numbers from the email body once the email is received

Tags: android, email

I'm new to android world. Is there any way to dial the phone numbers that is received from specific email address so that when the email is received, the No that is appear in the subject or content in the email will be dialed automatically without user interaction

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "directly", but there's a way to detect phone numbers inside a `String` and make it clickable and leading to the Phone application. This is done using the [Linkify](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify.html) class. For example, you can call the following method on the `TextView` containing the message and `Linkify` makes every phone number it detects clickable.

```
Linkify.addLinks(textView, Linkify.PHONE_NUMBERS);
```

Hope this helps.